# Why the service is not getting stop?

Tags: android, intentservice

Hi i am blinking the flashlight on incoming call and i am able to do that using this code but the problem is the flashlight is not getting stopped when the call is attended or cut
I am trying to stop the service from every way but the flashlight doesnot stops untill the loop is completed
In receiver class...

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, Run.class);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                in.putExtra("state", state);
                context.startService(in);
            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                // Toast.makeText(context, "Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.stopService(in);

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                // Toast.makeText(context, "Offhook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                context.stopService(in);
            }
```

In Service class...

```
Camera cam;
    Parameters p;
    String state;
    String tag="Runserve";
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        try {


            cam = Camera.open();
            p = cam.getParameters();

            String myString = "0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011";
            long blinkDelay = 50;


            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

                    break;                  

                    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                    break;  
                    }               

                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                } else {
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                }

                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d(tag, "in catch1");
            Log.d(tag, e.toString());

    }
}else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
    try {
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d(tag, e.toString());
    }

    stopSelf();
    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        try {

            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            cam.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d(tag, e.toString());
        }

        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

I am making the app in which i can attend the call through proximity sensor.This code has 2 intents First is i i.e working for versions less than Android 4.0 and another is headSetUnPluggedintent i.e working on Android 4.1. Is there any single way through which calls can be attended by all versions

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int callState = mgr.getCallState();


        if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

            callState = mgr.getCallState();
            String x="0.0";
            String y=(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
                if( x.equals(y)){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Proxy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try{

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);

                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

                    Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
                    headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
                    headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 0);
                    headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
                    sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
                    if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                        headSetUnPluggedintent=null;
                        i=null;
                    }else if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                        headSetUnPluggedintent=null;
                        i=null;
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(tag, e.toString());
                }
                }
```

Comment: Update the value of state after cut call or receive call.

Comment: you are absolutely right and i updated this thing still it is not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points here :

- in the for loop, it's useless to check the value of `state` as you have already checked it in your if condition. state is a `String` (i.e.immutable), it's value is not going to change.
- you need to get, for each iteration, the **current** state of the call, using [TelephonyManager#getCallState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). Something like this (not tested) :

  ```
  TelephonyManager mgr = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  int callState = mgr.getCallState();
  if (callState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING )
      break;
  ```
- You should normally not attempt to stop a `IntentService`, it stops itself when all work is done (that is when `onHandleIntent` returns).
  Also, the [IntentService javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) states that you should not call stopSelf().

Comment: ok i will update that thing and i have updated my code by getting state updated everytime in loop but still the flashlight is not stopping

Comment: please post your updated code, otherwise there's not way to know what's going.

Comment: you may see that i am getting the current state of call in for loop

Comment: No, you are still getting the extra from the Intent, which value is the sate when the Intent was fired, and is never updated.

Comment: if you dont mind i have one very small query could you please answer that also  i.e  in my code sometimes camera.open doesnot works and it gives runtime exception i.e unable to connect camera service

Comment: I cannot say from the code you posted, you should create a new question for this issue.

Comment: I have post the question kindly could you see one time please... http://stackoverflow.com/q/22384693/3409600

Comment: I have this small query also could you please solve and last thing i want to confirm from you that whether i am checking the state right in this code

Comment: could you please tell what is the state when phone is locked by user on incoming call, when user wants to put the phone on silence by clicking the power button