# What should i do so that camera work everytime?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using camera service in my application. Sometimes the camera service is running fine in the application and sometimes it gives a runtime exception.

I have put Camera.Open() in try block and i have catched the exception and its showing in log cat

```
03-12 13:52:42.211: D/crazy(12686): in catch1
03-12 13:52:42.211: D/crazy(12686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

The code that i done is...

```
    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            int callState = mgr.getCallState();

            //state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            try {


                cam = Camera.open();
                p = cam.getParameters();

                String myString = "0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011";
                long blinkDelay = 50;


                for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                    //state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    callState = mgr.getCallState();
                    if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.release();
                        break;                  

                        }else if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.release();
                        break;  
                        }               

                    if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        cam.setParameters(p);
                    } else {
                        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        cam.setParameters(p);
                    }

                        Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);

                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d(tag, "in catch1");
                Log.d(tag, e.toString());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because it is already used.

The javadoc for [open](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) states :

> If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.
>
> You must call release() when you are done using the camera, otherwise it will remain locked and be unavailable to other applications.
>
> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera.

Make sure you always release the camera (even in case of exception, use `finally`) and check if there is no other application using it.

Comment: Could you please look over this problem of mine... http://stackoverflow.com/q/22485031/3409600

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the [android docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html). So long as you remember to release the camera when you're done (at at least before you try to get a new instance) you should be fine. I recommend reading the rest of that document as well. It is very helpful.

private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

```
try {
    releaseCameraAndPreview();
    mCamera = Camera.open(id);
    qOpened = (mCamera != null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

   return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    mPreview.setCamera(null);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please look over this problem of mine... stackoverflow.com/q/22485031/3409600